# Can't call class from another file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to change screens when one button is pressed in flutter. When the two classes of the screens are in the same file everything works fine but when I put the second class in another file it doesn't work.
Here is the button code:

```
TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Change Screen',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ScreenB(),
                    ));
                  },
                )
```

and here is the second screen code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenB extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenB({super.key});

  @override
  State<ScreenB> createState() => _ScreenBState();
}

class _ScreenBState extends State<ScreenB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Navigator.push` as follows:

```dart
 TextButton(
      child: const Text(
        'Change Screen',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()),
        );
      },
    );
```